# Node setup for alpha and translucency maps

Tags: texturing, node-editor, image

There is a whole new set of [photoscanned objects](https://www.textures.com/browse/3d-scans/114548) from [textures.com](https://www.textures.com): grass. Taking as an example the [3D Scanned Grass Atlas 11 set](https://www.textures.com/download/3dscans0204/132473), one can find multiple `tiff` files that can be used in blender as image textures (those can be downloaded with a free account at low resolution):

- albedo
- normal
- roughness
- translucency
- alpha

Here is my node setup.

[image]

I don't know if it is right (node editor beginner here). And what should I do with the alpha map?

Obviously, there is something wrong with my setup.

[image]

Comment: Watch Andrew Prices's  [How to Use the Principled Shader](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/2017/6/21/how-to-use-blenders-new-ultimate-shader-principled-bsdf)

Comment: @cegaton I already did but it's been a while. I'll watch it again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Albedo -> Color

Roughness (Non-Color Data) -> Roughness

Translucent -> Transmission

Normal (Non-Color Data) -> Normal (Tangent Space) -> Normal

Alpha is used on a mix shader to control the mix of the principled shader and transparency.

[image]

Comment: Thanks (+1)! Why don't we set image to non color data for translucent and alpha?

Comment: @cjorssen Yes, alpha should be non-color. And translucent... I'm not sure since the original image does contain color information...